# How many number of tasks can I add in a Tasks?

Tags: java, android

I want to execute multiple tasks at once. I wonder what is the maximum number of tasks I can add in a single Tasks.

Here is an example:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(tasks)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Object>> task) {
                    helper.dismissProgressDialog();

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard-coded maximum number of tasks that the `Tasks` library can handle (as far as I know). There is probably a physical limit that the device you run the code on can handle (based on memory usage) or that your user is willing to wait (based on the time it takes to execute the tasks), but there's no way for the `Tasks` library to know that.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was informative.